# Julia: Floats sum is wrong?

Tags: julia

How can I make sure that by adding `0.2` at every iteration I get the correct result?

```
some = 0.0
for i in 1:10
    some += 0.2
    println(some)
end
```

the code above gives me

```
0.2
0.4
0.6000000000000001
0.8
1.0
1.2
1.4
1.5999999999999999
1.7999999999999998
1.9999999999999998
```

Comment: You can't: it's a fundamental limitation of floating point arithmetic, widely used in computer programming, including Julia: https://0.30000000000000004.com/.  You may use arbitrary precision numbers ([BigFloat](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/#BigFloats-and-BigInts) in Julia) or other kind of arithmetic (e.g., [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic), there are packages for that also in Julia) put if you want to stick to the standard `Float64` there is no way around this and you must live with this limitation.

Comment: you can use compensation to reduce the error, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floats are only approximatively correct and if adding up to infinity the error will become infinite, but you can still calculate with it pretty precisely. If you need to evaluate the result and look if it is correct you can use `isapprox(a,b)` or `a ≈ b`.

I.e.

```
some = 0.
for i in 1:1000000
    some += 0.2
end
isapprox(some, 1000000 * 0.2)
# true
```

Otherwise, you can add integer numbers in the for loop and then divide by 10.

```
some = 0.
for i in 1:10
    some += 2.
    println(some/10.)
end
#0.2
#0.4
#0.6
#0.8
#1.0
#1.2
#1.4
#1.6
#1.8
#2.0
```

More info about counting with floats:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: Option three: use fractions. `some = 0//1`, `some += 1//5`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over a range since they use some clever tricks to return more "natural" values:

```
julia> collect(0:0.2:2)
11-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.2
 0.4
 0.6
 0.8
 1.0
 1.2
 1.4
 1.6
 1.8
 2.0

julia> collect(range(0.0, step=0.2, length=11))
11-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.2
 0.4
 0.6
 0.8
 1.0
 1.2
 1.4
 1.6
 1.8
 2.0
```